# Hash error when "run apt-get update" in dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/universe/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/d370386524650f704ea8fba1620b2ea292dbb4bae271eee911ea923a72dba43c  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:1057917 [weak]
    - SHA256:d370386524650f704ea8fba1620b2ea292dbb4bae271eee911ea923a72dba43c
    - SHA1:52b3ffc19be0c867511f910ef4fedcb12d254351 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:21c77a2b02b923bce7ad7f995be64832 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:3374730f876ee981d95617e4a67a7fae9c06bfa8a773ef018eb8988bc1b3b221
    - SHA1:8c5eff415eb65ee6bbb22b9bc0530b251c5bf9c6 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:011041ee712359f6b601a06ed2dbe66b [weak]
    - Filesize:1057917 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 07:37:27 +0000
   Release file created at: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 10:05:57 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get clean` before update

Comment: running a dockerfile and sudo does not work and also just apt-get clean doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

I needed to change the sources.list by adding this code to the dockerfile

```
RUN sed -i 's/archive.ubuntu.com/mirrors.163.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list 
RUN apt-get clean
```